# How to calculate total / max electricity consumpton for a server / or hardware equipment.?

Tags: power-supply-unit

Consider I have in the cisco 2911-sec/k9 data sheet following power values

- Maximum Power with AC Power Supply (Watts) 210

With this given value how can one calculate total electricity produced or consumed?

What the involved? I want to use this figure to find out total billing cost?

**UPDATE**

The data sheet for the particular switch have following values for power specifications.

- AC Input Voltage
- AC Input Frequency
- AC Input Current Range AC Power Supply (Maximum)
- AC Input Surge Current
- Typical Power (No Modules) (Watts)
- Maximum Power with AC Power Supply (Watts)

I want to know what value should i be using for my calculation to find maximum power requirements?

Comment: Nameplate power ratings are maximums -- the typical power draw will be less, depending on your loading and usage pattern.  The most reliable way to check is to use a power meter to measure your actual consumption.

Comment: @mpez0 so if i look at the power rating value of the product it would give me the rough figure ? is that right.

Answer (score 0):

Watts are a measure of power (energy over time). 210 watts means that the device will use 210 Watts over the course of an hour.  Your energy bill is calculated in Kilowatt hours, or the number of Kilowatts you use per hour.

So take all of the ratings of all of your equipment, add them up, convert the watts to kilowatts (divide by 1000) and then multiply the result by the rate that the energy company charges per kilowatt hour (this is sometimes variable, depends on your company) and you'll have how much you'll pay per hour.  Next multiply by the number of hours you have the devices on per day (if 24 hours, multiply by 24) to get your daily charge.  next multiply by the number of days in the month to get your monthly charge.  You could take the monthly charge and multiply it by 12 or the daily charge by 365 to get a ball park figure for how much per year you're being charged, but keep in mind the price of electricity can sometimes fluctuate from month to month.

Comment: Still the same calculation, power is all that matters because that's all you're paying for.  Everything else is important for determining the quality of the electricity.  Just keep in mind, as others have said that it's a maximum calculation, You'll likely draw less, but better to over budget at first, until you get a feel.